# Getting FFT frequency from noisy data?

Tags: java, android, fft, frequency

I have an array (size 128) of data that I am using FFT on. I am trying to find the frequency of the data through the FFT spectrum. The problem is that the formula `freq = i * Fs / N` doesn't seem to be working. My data is quite noisy and I don't know if it is because of my noisy data or because I am doing something else wrong. Below is my raw data:

[image: Raw Data]

And this is the spectrum that results from the transform:

[image: Spectrum]

I am getting two maximum peaks of equal magnitude at index 4 and 128 in the output array. The frequency of the data should be around 1.1333 Hz, but I am getting 5-6 or completely wrong values when I use the formula:

```
freq = i * Fs / N;
```

where `i` is the array index of the largest magnitude peak, `Fs` is the sampling rate in Hz, and `N` is the data size.

Using my data, you get `freq = (4 * 11.9) / 128` = 0.37 Hz, which is very off from what is expected.

If my calculation is correct, are there any ways to improve my data? Or, are my calculations for frequency incorrect?

Comment: For one your spectrum seems to contain 256 points, so I'm guessing you are plotting interleaved real & imaginary parts rather than the magnitudes. If `i` is the index shown in your Spectrum plot, then the result will be off by a factor of 2 (not helping your case though). Then you have a strong average value/very low frequency component (the section of raw data varies between 98-100, instead of near 0) which would naturally appear in the lower spectrum bins. Remove that bias and you might better see spectrum peaks associated with you data oscillations.

Comment: By the strong average value do you mean the peaks on the edges of the spectrum? I removed around 1/5th of the spectrum on each side and got this: [image link](http://imgur.com/Fc4ExB3) . So I'm guessing my data is just too noisy to create an accurate frequency spectrum?

Comment: I'm also confused about the index of the maximum magnitude. Assuming there are 256 data points, and imaginary parts are interleaved, if the highest magnitude was at index 90, would I say i = 45 since the 45th real value would be at index 90?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is this Fourier Analysis of Luminance Signals Correct? (Android)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33539979/is-this-fourier-analysis-of-luminance-signals-correct-android)

Answer (score 1):

Lets first make sure you are looking at the actual magnitudes. FFTs would return complex values associated with each frequency bins. These complex values are typically represented by two values: one for the real part and another for the imaginary part. The magnitude of a frequency component can then be obtained by computing `sqrt(real*real+imaginary*imaginary)`.

This should give you half as many values and the corresponding spectrum (with the magnitudes expressed in decibels):

[image]

As you can see there is a strong peak near 0Hz. Which is consistent with your raw data having a large average value, as well as an increasing trend from time 0 to ~4.2s (both of which being larger than the oscillations' amplitude). If we were to remove these low frequency contributions (with for example a high-pass filter with cutoff frequency around 0.25Hz) we would get the following fluctuation data:

[image]

with the corresponding spectrum:

[image]

As you can see the oscillation frequency can much more readily be observed in bin 11, which gives you `freq = (11 * 11.9) / 128` = 1Hz.

Note however that whether removing these frequency components bellow 0.25HZ is an *improvement* of your data depends on whether those frequency components are of interest for your application (possibly not since you seem to be interested in relatively faster fluctuations).

Answer (score -1):

You need to remove the DC bias (average of all samples) before the FFT to measure frequencies near 0 Hz (or near the FFT's 0th result bin).  Applying a window function (von Hann or Hamming window) after removing the DC bias and before the FFT may also help.